# How to refactor this method C# Window

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a TextBox to search all occurences of the entered text in RichTextBox Control.
The result will be populated in a listbox for traversal pupose after the search gets over.

I have written following function to achieve thedesired result.. but its taking good amount of time to complete.. I need some suggestion to fix this issue

In short I need to implement FindAll feature..

```
public void FindSearchResults(string searchWord)
{
    CheckState matchCase = default(CheckState);
    CheckState matchWholeWords = default(CheckState);
    RichTextBox tvc = this._rt;
    List<string> retVal = new List<string>();
    RichTextBoxFinds FindOptions = default(RichTextBoxFinds);

    currentSearchWord = searchWord;
    FindOptions = RichTextBoxFinds.None;
    // Location to begin the search. 
    FindOptions = RichTextBoxFinds.None;

    int searchResult = -2;
    int start = 0;
    string expandedValue = "";
    if ((matchWholeWords == CheckState.Checked) & (matchCase == CheckState.Checked))
    {
        FindOptions = RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase | RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord;
    }
    else if ((matchWholeWords == CheckState.Checked))
    {
        FindOptions = RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord;
    }
    else if ((matchCase == CheckState.Checked))
    {
        FindOptions = RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase;
    }
    else
    {
        FindOptions = RichTextBoxFinds.None;
    }
    while (searchResult != -1 & start < tvc.Text.Length)
    {
        searchResult = tvc.Find(searchWord, start, FindOptions);
        if ((searchResult != -1))
        {
            expandedValue = Expand(searchWord, searchResult);
            while (searchResultList.ContainsKey(expandedValue))
            {
                // just to keep uniqueness 
                expandedValue = expandedValue + " ";
            }

            retVal.Add(expandedValue);
            searchResultList[expandedValue] = searchResult;
            start = searchResult + searchWord.Length;
        }
    }

}

private string Expand(string searchWord, int searchResult)
{
    string retVal = null;
    int startPos = 0;
    int endPos = 0;
    int spaceCount = 0;
    RichTextBox tvc = this._rt;

    startPos = searchResult;
    spaceCount = 0;
    while (spaceCount < 2 & startPos > 0)
    {
        startPos = startPos - 1;
        char[] ch=tvc.Text.Substring(startPos,1).ToCharArray();
        if (ch[0] == (Char)32)
        {
            spaceCount = spaceCount + 1;
        }
    }

    spaceCount = 0;
    endPos = searchResult + 1;

    while (spaceCount < 4 & endPos < tvc.Text.Length)
    {
        int asciiVal = 0;
        asciiVal = Strings.Asc(tvc.Text.Substring(endPos,1));
        if (asciiVal == 10 | asciiVal == 13 | asciiVal == 32)
        {
            spaceCount = spaceCount + 1;
        }
        endPos = endPos + 1;
    }

    retVal = tvc.Text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos);
    retVal = retVal.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Could you please use Code Formatter please.

Comment: <pedantic_mode>
Refactoring generally means rewriting the code to improve the design/maintainability without changing what the code actually does.

Since you want the performance to improve I think you mean "re-write" rather than "refactor".
</pedantic_mode>

Comment: Well I have barely managed to make it readable.. dont know too many tweaks of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your code is not very clear currently. To start with, I would:

- Do a clear split between the bits that determine search parameters
- Do the actual search (this method shouldn't reference any UI components)
- Display the results

It is not obvious (for me at least) what are your methods doing. What is the Expand method doing? Why is it using the edit box?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not the cleanest and could definitely use refactoring, but I think you should probably look at executing the Find method in chunks when searching for text.  Additionally when you're looking for stop chars like ' ' you should search in chunks.  My queries seem to run pretty fast against the Find method.

```
private void FindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        findOptions = default(RichTextBoxFinds);
        resultsListBox.Items.Clear();

        if (MatchCaseCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            findOptions = findOptions | RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase;
        }

        if (MatchEntireWordCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            findOptions = findOptions | RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord;
        }

        int[] foundLocations = FindSearchResults(TextToSearchTextBox.Text.Trim());
        string[] words = null;
        if (foundLocations.Length > 0)
        {
            words = GetWords(foundLocations);

        }
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            resultsListBox.Items.Add(word);
        }
    }

    private string[] GetWords(int[] foundLocations)
    {
        string textChunk = string.Empty;
        int chunkSize = 64;
        int textLength = MyRichTextBox.TextLength;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        int lastSpaceIndex = -1;
        int firstSpaceIndex = -1;
        foreach (int location in foundLocations)
        {
            textChunk = string.Empty;
            startIndex = location;
            endIndex = location;
            firstSpaceIndex = -1;
            lastSpaceIndex = -1;

            //get the start index.
            while (startIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (startIndex - chunkSize >= 0)
                {
                    startIndex -= chunkSize;
                }
                else
                {
                    startIndex -= Math.Abs(startIndex);
                }

                textChunk += MyRichTextBox.Text.Substring(startIndex, location - startIndex);
                firstSpaceIndex = textChunk.LastIndexOf(' ');
                if (firstSpaceIndex > -1)
                {
                    firstSpaceIndex = location - (textChunk.Length - firstSpaceIndex);
                    break;
                }
            }
            textChunk = string.Empty;
            startIndex = location;
            if (firstSpaceIndex == -1)
            {
                firstSpaceIndex = 0;
            }

            while (textChunk.Length <= textLength)
            {
                if (chunkSize + location < textLength)
                {
                    endIndex = chunkSize;
                }
                else
                {
                    endIndex = (textLength - startIndex);
                }

                textChunk += MyRichTextBox.Text.Substring(firstSpaceIndex + 1,
                    endIndex);
                lastSpaceIndex = textChunk.IndexOf(' ');
                if (lastSpaceIndex > -1)
                {
                    words.Add(textChunk.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return words.ToArray();
    }

    private int[] FindSearchResults(string textToSearchFor)
    {

        int textLength = MyRichTextBox.TextLength;
        int chunkSize = 128;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        int foundIndex = -1;
        List<int> foundLocations = new List<int>();

        while (startIndex < textLength)
        {
            if ((chunkSize + startIndex) < textLength)
            {
                endIndex += chunkSize;
            }
            else
            {
                endIndex += textLength - endIndex;
            }

            foundIndex = MyRichTextBox.Find(textToSearchFor, startIndex, endIndex, findOptions);
            if (foundIndex > -1)
            {
                foundLocations.Add(foundIndex);
            }
            startIndex += chunkSize;
        }

        return foundLocations.ToArray();
    }
```